# Can not simulate press in Enzyme because node is not found

Tags: javascript, react-native, enzyme

I have a React Native class called `MyClass` with this `render` method:

```
render() {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.showAllData}>
            //some other code
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );
}
```

In am trying to test it with Enzyme like this:

```
    const wrapper = shallow(
        <MyClass/>
    );
    wrapper.find(<TouchableHighlight/>).simulate('press');
    expect(wrapper.find(<Text> {Constants.MY_CONSTANT} </Text>)).to.have.length(0);
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
Method “simulate” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.
```

So why can it not find `<TouchableHighlight/>`?

How can I make `<TouchableHighlight/>` visible to the test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
wrapper.find(<TouchableHighlight/>).simulate('press');
```

try:

```
wrapper.find(TouchableHighlight).simulate('press');
```

If that doesn't work, also try:

```
wrapper.find('TouchableHighlight').simulate('press');
```

The first change should work, but in certain scenarios (especially if this is a simplified example), it'll get a little confused and you'll want to find it with a string name instead of the class.

Comment: Thank you, that sorted it. Now the last line fails with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined`. Do you know by any chance how to fix that as well?

Comment: Likely the same deal. You can't give it an element. Instead, you'll have to give it the class name `Text` and then check it in some other way if you have multiple `Text` elements and you want to make sure one isn't there.